# How to configure Nginx as reverse proxy server?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I try to create proxy server using Nginx.

I need configure Nginx that if I request any URL address as client, Nginx must return this URL page immediately. For example I request page using param `url` from my server:

```
http://myserver.com/url=www.gogo.com
```

Nginx should return me page `www.gogo.com`

I tried in location:

```
proxy_pass $host
```

Answer (score 0):

Url should contain the protocal(http/https) later on

Use IP resolver based on url belongs to your intranet or internet

For internet 8.8.8.8